# When does QVBoxLayout recalculate the layout?

Tags: c++, windows, linux, qt, qtgui

I have a window with a a QVBoxLayout in it. The layout has some child widgets (defined in a .ui file). In my window class' constructor, I create and assign a menu to the layout. The position of the widgets is supposed to shift down, since the menu takes some vertical space. This does not occur immediately - if I query the top child widget's Y coordinate right after the setMenuBar() call, it's still zero.

Question - when does the layout recalculate the positions of its children? Can I force it to?

Comment: Have you tried update()?

Comment: I'm confused.  You seem to be saying you stuck a QMenu into a layout.  I wouldn't expect that to do anything nice.

Comment: I stuck a QMenuBar there. And the menu displays as expected. And the child widgets do shift down. Except it happens at some point past the constructor.

Comment: @Noah: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qlayout.html#setMenuBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this:
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qlayout.html#activate